# Cant flash after preUpdate event

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is what I do in  even preUpdate

```
 public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof Order) {
        if ($args->hasChangedField('status') && $args->getNewValue('status') == 'stock') {
            $this->container->get('activity_logger')->writeLog($entity, 'purchase');
        }
    }
```

This is where I have error

> FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds
>   exceeded in /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 2498

```
public function writeLog ($object, $comment)
    {

        $entity = new Stock();
        $entity->setCategory($object->getIsotope()->getCategory()->getId());
        $entity->setComment($comment);
        $entity->setDate(new \DateTime('now'));
        $entity->setUser($object->getUser()->getId());
        $entity->setChange(TRUE);


        $this->em->persist($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
}
```

There are store a new entity another way?

find not very nice solution(do it manually) its save and dont touch events

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ('foo', 'var')";
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('invoice', $invoiceId);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't do this because the output of a managed Entity contains recursive fields.

Take a look at https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle :) And log the serialized version ;)

Answer (score 0):

To do that I store the newly created entities in a private array in the EventSuscriber. Then on the onFlush part of the suscriber if that array length is greater than 0 I persist them with a foreach loop. Then, outside the foreach loop, I clear the array (this is very important to prevent infinite loop) and finally call the flush.